# Trying to install rtx 3070 driver

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I faced many issues with my laptop and spent around 3 days,

I have alienware m15 R4 with rtx 3070 laptop edition.

The first problem i was unable to boot so that i added nomodeset in grub configuration.

Now i'm able to login. and tried to install rtx 3070 driver from this  [link](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/166177/en-us) or even from the software updater but this causes to nothing open at normal boot neither
recovery mode and it keeps a black blank screen with no options even a restart this means ALT+CTRL+del not working also and nothing can be opened so i need to force power off my laptop.

What is the correct way to install this driver ?

Note that now ubuntu is detecting the graphic card  as llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits) instead of rtx 3070
another note the secure boot is off

Comment: Try the Nvidia 465 driver from the standard repositories (460 still might be the "tested/recommended one, so 465 is further down the list).

Answer (score 1):

the official way to install proprietary drivers in ubuntu linux:

1. Open "Software & Drivers" (Press Win key and enter "drivers" in search bar)
2. Open Tab "Additional Drivers"
3. check "Using NVIDIA drivers [...]"
4. hit "Apply Changes"
5. you are now kindly asked to reboot. do so.

if u are more experienced: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` will install latest recommended drivers for your system from ubuntu repositrory (: